# How to set socks proxy username/password in java mail

Tags: proxy, jakarta-mail, socks

I am using javamail for sending mail (SMTP protocol) as follows

```
String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
:
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

props.put("mail.smtp.socks.host","sock_proxy_host");
props.put("mail.smtp.socks.port","sock_proxy_port");

Session session = Session.getInstance(props,new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("..", "..");
        }
});
```

But the socks proxy i am using requires a basic authentication. I am trying to setting the credential as

```
System.setProperty("java.net.socks.username", "socks_username");             
System.setProperty("java.net.socks.password", "socks_passwd");
```

Is there any other way to set the socks proxy username/password (using javamail API)?

Comment: JavaMail uses the java.net.Proxy class to provide SOCKS support, which unfortunately doesn't allow specifying the username and password for the proxy.  Hopefully setting an Authenticator as suggested below will work.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html#Proxies), the java.net.socks.username property is only consulted if there is no java.net.Authenticator set.  Perhaps some other code in your JVM has set a default Authenticator?  If you have appropriate permission, try [setting your own default java.net.Authenticator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Authenticator.html#setDefault%28java.net.Authenticator%29).

Answer (score 0):

You should define a class implementation from java.net.Authenticator:

```
java.net.Authenticator authenticator = new java.net.Authenticator() {

 protected java.net.PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
      return new java.net.PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());
      }
 };

System.setProperty("java.net.socks.username", username); 
System.setProperty("java.net.socks.password", password); 
java.net.Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaMail doesn't support proxy authentication, only anonymous SOCKS proxy. I don't know of any java library that does except [Simple Java Mail](http://www.simplejavamail.org), which is open source.

Simple Java Mail adds support for authenticated proxy using [a trick](http://www.simplejavamail.org/#/features): it runs a temporary anonymous SOCKS server for JavaMail to connect to on the same host and then relays the connection by manually authenticating to an external SOCKS proxy outside of JavaMail.

Here's your code again, but this time using Simple Java Mail:

```java
Mailer mailer = new Mailer(
        new ServerConfig("smtp.gmail.com", thePort, "..", ".."),
        TransportStrategy.SMTP_TLS,
        new ProxyConfig("sock_proxy_host", "sock_proxy_port", socks_username, socks_passwd)
);

mailer.sendMail(email);
```

You don't need to set any property or other configuration, it's all taken care of.